# Android - how to remove the "input method" popup?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I have an application with a WebView. The WebView opens a page and there is a input field on the page. If the users clicks on the input field and presses for long some of the submission buttons, a "input method" popup appears (from Android).

How can I remove this popup? I tried override-ing the onTouch, onKeyLongPress and some other methods to return false, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It sounds like you have another problem that you are trying to fix the wrong way.  Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: You are quite right - problem was quite not where I thought it was. Problem has been fixed though, with no whatsoever tweaking of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to remove that at all. It's like a chooser for different on-screen keyboards.

In order to remove it, you have to remove the keyboards from the settings. If there is one, it won't be displayed, but this is a user choice.

Comment: Can't I set the application to use one exact inputMode? Is there no such possibility ?

Comment: @George: You have no right to dictate to the user what input method to use, any more than you have the right to dictate to the user what color pants they are allowed to wear.

Comment: What I meant to say is that I need to remove the popup, which is being problematic on one particular activity. I though by choosing a specific input method (soft onscreen keyboard for example) for the current activity would solve the issue for me, but there are better and clearer ways to say that this is problematic and abusing the user in some way. Still, thanks for your post.